# Paste option is greyed out in context menu

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

On right click in File explorer (Nautilus) this happens (options are 'create new folder', 'create new document', etc). It does not happen on applications such as Firefox, Writer, etc.

I know this happened after I made I clean install to 12.04 but I do not know if it happened since the install or after.

Even though the option is greyed out I can still paste if I click it, or Ctrl+V.

Any idea?

Comment: it's a bug, reported here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/949468

Comment: Try your updating your system after fresh install. Might have fixed.

Comment: This bug you are experiencing has already been documented as a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/882307). If you have queries, please post comments in the bug report. I am now proceeding to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: have you try run nautilus as root? Maybe ubuntu prevent you from editing root folder/configuration.

Comment: It has been corrected with the updates from last week! how cnan I close this?

Comment: Also reported here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686396

Comment: @quinestor, what do you mean when you say the updates from last week (mid 2012) have it corrected? I've updated 12.04 regularly but the problem persists.